# Show main tag description below synonym tag

Tags: feature-request, tag-synonyms, tags-page

[Tags page](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/tags?tab=new).

There is no description shown below synonym tag. But when you hover this tag, you can see description in the tooltip.

> [image]

Could you show main tag description below synonym tag?